# V8 JavaScript Object vs Binary Tree

Tags: node.js, object, binary-tree, v8

Is there a faster way to search data in `JavaScript` (specifically on `V8` via `node.js`, but without c/c++ modules) than using the `JavaScript` `Object`?

[This may be outdated](https://developers.google.com/v8/design?hl=en#prop_access) but it suggests a new class is dynamically generated for every single property.  Which made me wonder if a binary tree implementation might be faster, however [this does not appear to be the case](http://jsperf.com/array-vs-binary-tree-test-23245).

The binary tree implementation isn't well balanced so it might get better with balancing (only the first 26 values are roughly balanced by hand.)

Does anyone have an idea on why or how it might be improved?  On another note: does the dynamic class notion mean there are actually ~260,000 properties (in the jsperf benchmark test of the second link) and subsequently chains of dynamic class definitions held in memory?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What is your use case? Have you performed benchmarks to decide that plain objects definitely will not work for your use case?

Comment: You really need to describe a specific use case.  "faster way to search data" does not describe what problem you're actually trying to solve.  This question, as it stands is far too unspecific.

Comment: The use case is searching keys within hundreds of thousands of records.  I thought that would be evident from the custom jsperf performance test attached to outline the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

V8 uses the concepts of 'maps', which describe the layout of the data in an object.

These maps can be "fast maps" which specify a fixed offset from the start of the object at which a particular property can be found, or they can be "dictionary map", which use a hashtable to provide a lookup mechanism.

Each object has a pointer to the map that describes it.

Generally, objects start off with a fast map. When a property is added to an object with a fast map, the map is transitioned to a new one which describes the location of the new property within the object. The object is re-allocated with enough space for the new data item if necessary, and the object's map pointer is set to the new map.

The old map keeps a record of the transitions from it, including a pointer to the new map and a description of the property whose addition caused the map transition.

If another object which has the old map gets the same property added (which is very common, since objects of the same type tend to get used in the same way), that object will just use the new map - V8 doesn't create a new map in this case.

However, once the number of properties goes over a certain theshold (in fact, the current metric is to do with the storage space used, not the actual number of properties), the object is changed to use a dictionary map. At this point the object is re-written using a hashtable. In general, it won't undergo any more map transitions - any more properties that are added will just go in the hashtable.

Fast maps allow V8 to generate optimized code (using Crankshaft) where the offset of a property within an object is hard-coded into the machine code. This makes it very fast for cases where it can do this - it avoids the need for doing any lookup.

Obviously, the generated machine code is then dependent on the map - if the object's data layout changes, the code has to be discarded and re-optimized when necessary. V8 has a type profiling mechanism which collects information about what the types of various objects are during execution of unoptimized code. It doesn't trigger optimization of the code until certain stability constraints are met - one of these is that the maps of objects used in the function aren't changing frequently.

[Here's a more detailed description of how this stuff works.](http://jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation)

[Here's a video where one of the lead developers of V8 describes stuff like map transitions and lots more.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWhMKalEicY)

For your particular test case, I would think that it goes through a few hundred map transitions while properties are being added in the preparation loop, then it will eventually transition to a dictionary based object. It certainly won't go through 260,000 of them.

Regarding your question about binary trees: a properly sized hashtable (with a sensible hash function and a significant number of objects in it) will always outperform a binary tree for a use-case where you're just searching, as your test code seems to do (all of the insertion is done in the setup phase).