# Class/structure members in a dynamic programming language interpreter

Tags: struct, interpreter

For statically typed languages member access is easy, you just calculate the offset of the member at compilation time. However how does ruby or python do it? There are maybe more structures with same member names and you are not even sure what kind of object a variable holds. Do they use some kind of dictionary to look up the member at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were implementing a dynamically typed language from scratch, that's probably where you would start - with something like a hashtable based dictionary, and it's a perfectly ok solution.

Some dynamic language runtimes optimized for size rather than performance (such as [Jerryscript](https://samsung.github.io/jerryscript/), a highly size-optimized Javascript interpreter) use this sort of approach exclusively, and it works fine.

However, most modern JIT-based dynamic language runtimes such as the V8 Javascript engine (used in Chrome and Node.js) or the JSC Javascript engine used in Safari only use this sort of dictionary as a fallback if they can't do anything better.

[Here's an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973327/v8-javascript-object-vs-binary-tree/35364419#35364419) where I described how V8 maps work and how they make property access very efficient. It contains a link to a much more detailed description, and a video by Lars Bak who is one of the lead engineers for V8, which is good if you're interested in how this stuff works.

With Ruby (as with Javascript), there are a number of different implementations (JRuby, MRI, Rubinius, etc), so to answer the question "How does Ruby do it" is difficult - each implementation will do it in a different way (although there will be many similarities, imposed by the language design).

Since you seemed to be asking about the concepts in dynamic languages in general, hopefully you'll find the link above gives you some useful information about possible implementations.